# Sion's ultimate speed

Tags: league-of-legends

In the 4.18 patch, Sion was reworked. I have some questions about the new Sion.

1st: If he is wearing `Ravenous hydra`(don't know if this is the correct item) will the kills from the hydra also add to the bonus health(which is in the 2nd skill passive now)?

2nd: Concerning his ultimate skill, do your boots come into play while "bull rushing"?

Comment: I don't quite get what your first point is... what do you mean with `will the kills from the hydra also goto the 2nd?`

Comment: You should ask a new question as a new question, not keep expanding one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer Both of your questions:

**Will the Ravenous Hydra kills also count towards his bonus health?**
Yes. Every unit you kill will give you bonus HP, no matter how you killed it. So you can basically use spells, Items or just Auto Attacks.

**Do your boots come into play when casting your ultimate?**
Yes they do. It is a movementspeed bonus but it's capped at 950 MS though, so you won't get any faster than that, however you will reach this cap faster with boots.

Comment: how much flat movement speed does he gain?

Comment: @PhilippSander Hmm I edited it out. I can't find the source right now but as far as I remember someone said it in an Interview I saw.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you refer to the Soul Furnace passive:

> Passive: Sion permanently gains 2 bonus health whenever he kills a unit, increased to 8 against large units and champion kills and assists.

Then it doesn't matter how you kill the unit, if you kill it you get the stack.

The ultimate speed doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so that's a good question.

Comment: i actually want to know if the bull rush will start with your initial speed with/out(350 something) boots or from 0.

Answer (score 0):

1st: i guess this question is about "his 2nd passive"

> Sion permanently gains 2 bonus health whenever he kills a unit, increased to 8 against large units and champion kills and assists.

Answer: **Yes it does!** All kills gain permanent health, no matter how.

2nd: **Having Boots makes you run faster**, but while Unstoppable Onslaught is active, Sion's movement speed is capped at 950.